AudioKit MIDISampler to play multiple samples
I have the following:
midiSampler.loadAudioFiles([lowBeatAudioFile, highBeatAudioFile])

I want them to behave like two instruments, so I can have 2 tracks corresponding to the 2 tracks.
It turns out only the last sample is used. Even with 2 tracks, both would play the second sample.
Questions:

If I want two instruments, do I need 2 samplers can send each track's MIDI output to corresponding sampler?


For those are not familiar with how AudioKit works:

Sampler is like an keyboard with one sample corresponding to each key (pitch)
AudioKit will register a sample to a certain pitch if you suffix the sample name with key names like "_D3" or "_F#4"
Otherwise it will only load the samples in order as MIDI pitch 0, 1, etc.
So if you need to use sampler as a drum kit, just load the samples to different pitches
You can have multiple tracks to play from one sampler, each track can play an drum kit timbre

